# Press Fn key Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyautogui

I bought a new keyboard and everytime I turn on my computer I have to press Fn + 5 (3 times) to set the color I want for the backlighting, so I decided to try to script it. 
First I tried with the pyautogui library:

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time

for x in range(0,2):
    pg.hotkey('fn','5')
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

But that didn't work since it didn't recognize the fn key.
Then I tried with the keyboard library and same problem. Lastly I tried with ctypes but there doesn't seem to be a virual key code for the Fn key.

Am I missing something or is there no way to automate a Fn + number press in windows?

Comment: the `fn` part seems perfectly fine according to the docs. are you sure its the `5` key? That one is weird to me. maybe you're thinking of `F5` key?

Comment: the code above just writes "5" 3 times, so the fn key doesn't get pressed. It's not F5 either, it's 5.

Comment: ah. I am afraid i do not have any personal experience with that library. the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys) here have `fn` listed, so i am not sure what could the issue be then. Should the code write `fn` anyways though? its not a keypress that writes anything. does a key like `ctrl` write something?

Comment: thx for the answer. I dont want it to write anything, I want it to press it. If I use ctrl + W or alt + F4 it closes the window, so the aproach is correct, the library just doesn't recognize my fn key for some reason.

Comment: Probably not core to your problem, but with “for x in range(0,2):” you are only pressing it twice, not three times...

Comment: Ok thx, still can't figure out why its not working though...

Comment: Did you find any way to detect Fn key press or any other alternative?

Comment: It seems that there is no event generation with 'fn' key.
Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/603345/alternate-for-fn-key-in-pyautogui-in-linux

So, your best bet is to rebind this hotkey to something not using/containing 'fn'.
If that is not possible, maybe use Arduino and attach some command with it that makes it to press 'fn' key on your keyboard whenever that command is executed. But it's opportunity cost maybe too high for it to be useful.

Answer (score 5):

There are keys for pressing fn+special keys:

for example for volume control:
'volumedown', 'volumemute', 'volumeup'

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('volumeup')
```

All the keys are in a list that you can access by typing

```
print(pyautogui.KEYBOARD_KEYS)
```

output:

```
['\t', '\n', '\r', ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~', 'accept', 'add', 'alt', 'altleft', 'altright', 'apps', 'backspace', 'browserback', 'browserfavorites', 'browserforward', 'browserhome', 'browserrefresh', 'browsersearch', 'browserstop', 'capslock', 'clear', 'convert', 'ctrl', 'ctrlleft', 'ctrlright', 'decimal', 'del', 'delete', 'divide', 'down', 'end', 'enter', 'esc', 'escape', 'execute', 'f1', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f2', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'final', 'fn', 'hanguel', 'hangul', 'hanja', 'help', 'home', 'insert', 'junja', 'kana', 'kanji', 'launchapp1', 'launchapp2', 'launchmail', 'launchmediaselect', 'left', 'modechange', 'multiply', 'nexttrack', 'nonconvert', 'num0', 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4', 'num5', 'num6', 'num7', 'num8', 'num9', 'numlock', 'pagedown', 'pageup', 'pause', 'pgdn', 'pgup', 'playpause', 'prevtrack', 'print', 'printscreen', 'prntscrn', 'prtsc', 'prtscr', 'return', 'right', 'scrolllock', 'select', 'separator', 'shift', 'shiftleft', 'shiftright', 'sleep', 'space', 'stop', 'subtract', 'tab', 'up', 'volumedown', 'volumemute', 'volumeup', 'win', 'winleft', 'winright', 'yen', 'command', 'option', 'optionleft', 'optionright']
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Fn" key is usually at the hardware level, programmed for an event. It does not send an input like the other keys on your keyboard. It just processes the key combination.


Pressing and releasing the key, does basically nothing.